# Android studio: sign apk for android without source code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I have an apk (for debug) and I want to sign it and modify identifier.
I tried to open it in android studio, but I cannot find build.gradle or another files.
I don't have the source code

Can you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: This what your looking for? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger#:~:text=To%20start%20debugging%20an%20APK,Android%20Studio%20and%20click%20OK.

Comment: you have to decompile debug apk to get code by using this link http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk   then get hint from this code to make your own new app in android studio then sign apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APK file is a binary file. It does not contain any source code or Android Studio project.

You can't sign a debug apk with another key.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: I have a documentation and sounds like this: You can download it from Google here: https://developer.android.com/studio
After downloading install it on your PC. 
After installation open your Android Studio and click “Open an existing Android Studio Project” and select your app (APK file which we sent you via email).

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding somewhere as APK doesn't contain project files. Clarify this point with your supplier